# how to find sensitivity and specificity for more than two levels in the dependent variable from the confusion matrix?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix, sensitivity-specificity

[image: For instance for this Confusution Matrix]

For the above confusion matrix how to compute the sensitivity and specificity manually. I cann't able to understand when the dependent variable has more than two levels

Comment: What is the scientific question which has brought you to thinking you need to compute these statistics?

Comment: I believe that sensitivity and specificity are not defined when there are more than two levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
The formulas are from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity).  Note that sensitivity and specificity depend on what you have defined as a "positive" in true positive and a "negative" in true negative.

In a 2x2, once you have picked one category as positive, the other is automatically negative. With 9 categories, you basically have 9 different sensitivities, depending on which of the nine categories you pick as "positive". You could calculate these by collapsing to a 2x2, i.e. Class1 versus not-Class1, then Class2 versus not-Class2, and so on.

An example: using the glass identification database, and Weka software, we get a confusion matrix for the 7 types of glass:

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

  a  b  c  d  e  f  g   <-- classified as
 50 15  3  0  0  1  1 |  a = build wind float
 16 47  6  0  2  3  2 |  b = build wind non-float
  5  5  6  0  0  1  0 |  c = vehic wind float
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 |  d = vehic wind non-float
  0  2  0  0 10  0  1 |  e = containers
  1  1  0  0  0  7  0 |  f = tableware
  3  2  0  0  0  1 23 |  g = headlamps
```

And we get a true positive rate (sensitivity) calculated for each type of glass, plus an overall weighted average:

```
=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
 0.714    0.174    0.667      0.714    0.690      0.532    0.806     0.667     build wind float
 0.618    0.181    0.653      0.618    0.635      0.443    0.768     0.606     build wind non-float
 0.353    0.046    0.400      0.353    0.375      0.325    0.766     0.251     vehic wind float
 0.000    0.000    0.000      0.000    0.000      0.000    ?         ?         vehic wind non-float
 0.769    0.010    0.833      0.769    0.800      0.788    0.872     0.575     containers
 0.778    0.029    0.538      0.778    0.636      0.629    0.930     0.527     tableware
 0.793    0.022    0.852      0.793    0.821      0.795    0.869     0.738     headlamps
 0.668    0.130    0.670      0.668    0.668      0.539    0.807     0.611     Weighted Avg.
```

(There is no `vehic wind non-float glass` in this data; that's why you see the "?".)